# Linking Redis database with a dump.rdb or dump.json file

Tags: redis, dump, database-restore

Given a snapshot of an existing redis database in a dump.rdb (or in .json format) file, I want to restore this data in my own machine to run some tests on it.

Any pointers on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

I have resorted to trying to parse the data in the dump.rdb and then save it in a redis DB manually. I feel like there is/should be a cleaner way.

Comment: SO:

I continued doing it the "hacky" way and found that using the parser code found here:
https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools was a great help.

using the parser sample code i could:
1) set up a redis client
2) use the parser to parse the data
3) use the client to "set" parsed data into a new redis database.

Comment: If you want to restore the entire file, simply copy it to the right directory specified in `redis.conf` and restart redis server. But if you want to load a subset of keys/database, you'd have to parse the dump file

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan why did you choose to answer this as a comment? This is the answer that I would have given.

Comment: @Fritzy My bad. Responding to the comment was almost mechanical. Moved to an answer now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restore the entire file, simply copy it to the right directory specified in `redis.conf` and restart redis server. But if you want to load a subset of keys/databases, you'd have to parse the dump file.

Answer (score 1):

SO:

I continued doing it the "hacky" way and found that using the parser code found here:
https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools was a great help.

using the parser sample code i could:
1) set up a redis client
2) use the parser to parse the data
3) use the client to "set" parsed data into a new redis database.

Answer (score 0):

the [rdd](https://github.com/r043v/rdd) tools can also do that,

it work independantly of .rdb files and dump/restore working redis instances

it can apply merge, split, rename, search, filter, insert, delete on dumps and/or redis