# How to load a redis database after

Tags: python, redis, persistence, reload

I understand how to save a redis database using bgsave.  However, once my database server restarts, how do I tell if a saved database is present and how do I load it into my application.  I can tolerate a few minutes of lost data, so I don't need to worry about an AOF, but I cannot tolerate the loss of, say, an hour's worth of data.  So doing a bgsave once an hour would work for me.  I just don't see how to reload the data back into the database.

If it makes a difference, I am working in Python.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10844337/521590

Comment: Redis loads automatically the rdb file when it starts :)

Answer (score 1):

You can stop redis and replace dump.rdb in /var/lib/redis (or whatever file is in the dbfilename variable in your redis.conf). Then start redis again.

Comment: What I have learned is that starting the redis-server automatically loads the state of the database into memory from the dump.rdb file.  I have written a demonstration python program that tests this.  [link](https://github.com/PythonCHB/PythonCertSpring/tree/master/week-05) test_redis_persistence.py

Comment: You can see from the redis stdout / log file that it is loading data from the rdb file when redis starts if it finds a file to load.